# Access to a specific element on an array using pointers C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am working to replace '.' by '::' in a phrase.
I am given a phrase with 30 caracteres, without using other array. I would like to access to the last element using a pointer.

However,
First I count the dots in my phrase.

```
actualSize= 0; i= 0;  dotNumb= 0;
while (i<actualSize){
if (tab[i]=='.') dotNumb++
i++
}
```

Now I should start by the end; whenever I find an element I move it, whenever I find a '.' I make an operation two times, by copying ':' two times.

Now I need to access to this element tab[dotNumb+actualSize]

Can I do it this way, or should I use pointers .

```
int newSize = dotNumb+actualSize ;
int j=newSize ;
int cursor=actualSize;

while (j>0){
if (tab[i]!='.') {tab[j]=tab[cursor]; }
else{tab[j]=':';tab[--j]=':';}
cursor--; j--;
}
```

Comment: It is slightly easier to use pointers, but either way will work.

Comment: That looks about right. Does it work? Be careful that tab is writable and large enough for the additional characters.

Comment: Did you mean "while (j>0)" instead of "while (j<0)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote does not work, (you made some typos, for example actualSize is set to 0 so the loop counting the dots will never execute. and the logic of your code would delete the character preceding a dot in the original array). You probably want something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *tab = malloc(30 + 1);
    if (tab == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(tab, "123456789.123456789.123456789.");
    printf("Original string: %s\n", tab);
    size_t actualSize = strlen(tab);

    int dotNumb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < actualSize; i++) {
        if (tab[i]=='.') {
            dotNumb++;
        }
     }
     const size_t newSize = dotNumb + actualSize + 1;
     tab = realloc (tab, newSize);
     if (tab == NULL) {
         /* leak memory previously allocated in tab */
         return -1;
     }
     tab[newSize] = '\0'; /* termination character */
     int j = newSize ;
     for (size_t cursor = actualSize; cursor > 0; cursor--) {
         if (tab[cursor] != '.') {
             tab[j--] = tab[cursor];
         }
         else { 
             tab[j--] = ':';
             tab[j--] = ':';
         }
    }
    printf("Modified string: %s\n", tab);
    return 0;
}
```

You can test the code here:
http://ideone.com/YOxJKo

Comment: The Prob is primarily in "Not using a new Array !". In this case, you don't want to count dots. You didn't understand the questions well.

Comment: Please answer my comment to your question, how big is the array with the 30 characters string?

Comment: it's a dynamic array with 30 caracteres initially, they gave us pointer address to first element

Comment: What do you mean char tab[30 + 1] = "123456789.123456789.123456789."

Comment: Yes! it's a dynamic array with 30 caracteres initially, they gave us pointer address to first element –

Comment: I modified my answer to use a dynamic array. You should probably edit your question to say you receive an array allocated dynamically (and caracteres is written characters in english ;-))

Comment: This not what I was asking about ! But It's working, I was asking about how to jump to the last element using a pointer. Thanks for your help

Comment: if (tab == NULL) {
         free(tab);
         return -1;
     } Good attempt at not leaking memory, but wrong. (free(NULL) is a no-op, and if realloc fails you don't have a pointer to the old memory)

Comment: You're right, then I'll edit and just leak the resource, with the constraint of not using a new array I don't see another solution ;-)

Comment: @user3001937 Your question of how to jump to the last element is impossible to answer, you didn't tell us how big the dynamic array you receive is, so I have no idea what the last element is.

Comment: Étienne : The length of the array is 50, and initially contain 30 characteres